# Autohotkey Check Variable in GUI

Tags: user-interface, variables, autohotkey, msgbox

I can't seem to get this message box to work using variables. It should be simple so I am missing something. Please help.

```
Gui +alwaysontop
Gui, add, button, gChoice vA w50, A
Gui, add, button, gChoice vB w50, B
gui, show, y200 w70
return

Choice:
msgbox % v
gui submit, nohide
if A
    MsgBox A
if B
    MsgBox B
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Issues with your code:

1. Ordinary buttons do not store anything in associated variables. So, specifying `vA` or `vB` is meaningless. On the other hand, checkboxes and radio buttons do, as stated [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#Checkbox).
2. I have no idea what you're trying to do with `MsgBox % v` since there's no other reference to the variable `v`.

The following's tested to work:

```
Gui +AlwaysOnTop
Gui Add, Button, gChoiceA w50, A
Gui Add, Button, gChoiceB w50, B
Gui Show, y200 w70
Return

ChoiceA:
    MsgBox A
Return

ChoiceB:
    MsgBox B
Return
```